# Использование переменных в crop django filer

Tags: html, django

При использовании полей django-filer, вставка данных из модели в html шаблон можно осуществить так:

```html
{% load thumbnail %}
{% thumbnail company.logo 250x250 crop %}
```

У меня в модели так же есть поля которые хранят ширину и высоту изображения. Но если вместо цифр подставляю данные из модели, данная вставка не работает:

```
{% thumbnail instance.image instance.img_widthxinstance.img_height  crop %}
```

Это то и понятно, что получается неверная вставка. Может кто знает как правильно и вообще возможно это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем обходное решение сделал на уровне моделей, путём добавления функции в модель плагина:

```
    def icrops(self):
        iсrop = (str(self.img_width) + str('x') + str(self.img_height))
        return icrop
```

А html шаблоне делаю вставку значения функции:

```
{% thumbnail instance.image instance.icrops crop %}
```

Работает как надо.